# Why do I get a "KeyError: 'data'" error when running a script?

Tags: python, tableau-api

I am using Tableau Prep Builder to run a Python script that pulls in an API from a data connector called Supermetrics. I am following closely along with their tutorial seen [here](https://supermetrics.com/blog/connect-data-to-tableau-prep-builder#step%202). When I run the script I get this message:

```
System error: Something went wrong when running the script. Verify that there are no errors in the script, then try again. KeyError : 'data'
```

This is the script:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
def get_data_to_flow(input):
    response = requests.get("[PLACEHOLDER FOR YOUR API LINK]")
    results = response.json()
    return pd.DataFrame(results['data'][1:], columns=results['data'][0])
```

The script worked initally but after running it the next day I started to see this error. I have followed the tutorial perfectly and have used an  API link that works. What does this error mean and how can I fix it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/. Do you understand the code? Do you know what a KeyError is? What part of the code do you think causes the error (hint: do you see a part of the code that says `'data'`, matching the error message)? What do you expect is the *type* of `results`, and why?

Comment: Your results do not have a `data` key.
Could you please print the results to see if everything is ok?

Comment: Please keep in mind as well that this is *not a discussion forum*. We do not want conversational language here, and we do not care about your level of experience with Python - except that, if you are new to the language then *you should learn the language first* before trying to use more advanced third-party libraries like `requests` and `pandas`, or web APIs like Tableau. Please try to follow a general Python tutorial from start to finish first.

Answer (score 1):

Because `results`, a dict, doesn't contain the key `data`. You aren't checking if your API returns valid data or not.

Call `raise_for_status()` on the response to get an error if the API returns an error.

Beyond that, maybe there isn't an error and shape of the data returned has changed since the last time you've used it?

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

def get_data_to_flow(input):
    response = requests.get("[PLACEHOLDER FOR YOUR API LINK]")
    response.raise_for_status()
    results = response.json()
    data = results['data']
    return pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns=data[0])
```